# Elasticsearch and fast changed data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with 1mln documents.

```
"mappings" : {
    "direct" : {
        "_source" : { "enabled" : true },
        "properties" : {
            "post" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "analyzed", "store" : false},
            "author" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "analyzed", "store" : false},
            "views_number" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed" , "store" : false}
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to change `views_number` every time someone visit the page with an `post`. I suggest, that this mapping is not good, as we need to reindex entire document each time. And it's very slow. Is there better solutions for this case?

Comment: Why do you suggest this mapping is slow? Your scenario is that you want to update `views_number` which is perhaps a counter. The only way to update is update the document. And in your case, do a script update if you are just incrementing. It will lead ES to eventually re-index the document and you can't escape that. That's just how ES handles updates - documents are not updated, but they are re-indexed with the new values under the hood.

Comment: @vaidik it's ok when you have single page and 1 views per 10 seconds.., but when you have 100k pages - you have at least 100 concurrent requests to ES, and things become unstable.

Comment: Hmm. Well 100 concurrent requests to ES is not that big a deal honestly. But if things look unstable to you, you can try some work around like using the Bulk API to update more documents in one go. So for example, store the latest 1000 page views in a separate data store and update them in one go using the Bulk API.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parent/child feature in Elasticsearch and make `post` a child of `direct`. that will make updating the `post` object quicker as you only need to update the individual 'post' document. Have a look at this blog post:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/